# How to argue a problem is NP

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I was given an example where the last letter of the first word is the first letter of the second word and the last letter of the second word was the first letter of the third word and so on...

So, the sentence "Hello other return neutral lax" would follow this convention

I was wondering how I may start to argue that this problem is in NP?

Comment: It is NP if you can show in polynomial time that a given solution is correct. In this case you can verify a proposed solution in linear time so it is NP.

Comment: I'm a little stuck on how I can verify a solution in linear time for this specific problem. Should I go about comparing it to another known algorithm and argue that it's np from there?

Comment: Solve this problem. Can you see how to do this with one pass through the string?

Comment: Oh, I see it now. thanks!